# why App crashes getting data from Dictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, nsdictionary

I am working on an app and i have to save some data in the dictionary and then i have to load that data and showing to user whatever the options user saved.
 when i get data from dictionary it crashes on second time not on first time and gives different crash log every time.
like

```
-[UIDeviceRGBColor objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68c22d0
```

or

```
[UIControlTargetAction count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68683d0
```

or

```
   0 : <CFString 0x687cb30 [0x124eb38]>{contents = "dish1"} = UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 0.5
```

my code is this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == menuTableView) {

        [optionsView addSubview:topScrollView];
        optionFlag=NO;
        [self optionScreenMethod:indexPath.row];
        NSString *dishSelect=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dish%d",indexPath.row];
        NSMutableArray *dishesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *dishDicArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        dishesArray=[dishDictionary objectForKey:dishSelect];
        NSLog(@"%d",[dishesArray count]);
        if ([dishesArray count]>0) {
            optionFlag=YES;
        }else{
            for (int i=0; i<[tempStr intValue]; i++) {
                DishData *dishData=[[DishData alloc]init];
                dishData.dishTitle=(NSMutableString*)[[tableMenuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] itemName];
                dishData.accompArrayIndex=nil;
                dishData.cookArrayIndex=nil;
                dishData.dishComent=nil;
                dishData.nonMandArray=nil;
                [dishDicArray addObject:dishData];
            }
            [dishDictionary setObject:dishDicArray forKey:dishSelect];
        }
        //[dishesArray release];
        //[dishDicArray release];
        dishSelectRow=indexPath.row;
      //  NSString *dishSelect=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dish%d",indexPath.row];
        
        [isSelected removeAllObjects];
        [isSelectedAccompArray removeAllObjects];
        [isSelectedCookArray removeAllObjects];
        [self defaultDataArray];
        [accompmentTblView reloadData];
        [cookingTblView reloadData];
        [nonMandTblView reloadData];
        [nonMandtSelectOptionArray removeAllObjects];

        optionsView.hidden=NO;

    }
```

Comment: where you define "dishDictionary"?

Comment: @Mashhadi I ve edited the answer check it out. May it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

       //If possible make a singleton instance here of "dishDictionary" may solve your issue of crashing (Rather diclare it at the class level)
      //if(!dishDictionary)
          dishDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

      ..........

      //Replace this line :
      NSMutableArray *dishDicArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

      to

      NSMutableArray *dishesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[dishDictionary objectForKey:dishSelect]];

      and remove
      dishesArray=[dishDictionary objectForKey:dishSelect];

      ..........
      //may will not crash than try this
}
```

Comment: Thanx its working but it crashes again when this code runs 3rd time at this line NSMutableArray *dishesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[dishDictionary objectForKey:dishSelect]];

Comment: I would suggest to alloc when it calls the didselect. Try the edited code, I just comment out 1 line from the code. And if it works well than plg accept the answer as true :) rather just commenting the answer